# What is this weird icon at top upper corner of the screen: 1

Tags: panel

What is the leftmost icon shown on my Ubuntu 18.04 screen's top right corner? It looks like a "1" enclosed by a rectangle.

I have googled and found nothing. Clicking on it does nothing.

Here is a photo of the top right part of my screen:

[image: photo of the top right part of my screen]

Comment: I thinks its a Indicator for NumLock.. Did you remember any recent changes you have done? any packages you installed etc?

Comment: In my opinion it's the workspace Icon, try to rightclick it, if there opens a menu telling something about workspace, then go to read this articles to find out how it works: https://websiteforstudents.com/what-are-workspaces-and-how-to-use-them-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/ https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en

Comment: Have you added Gnome Extensions on to your system?

Comment: to PRATAP:  No, I have NumLock install, when turned on, it show A enclosed in a rectangular

Comment: to cargli:   click on it, right click on it, both does nothing, this icon is like a dead icon.

Comment: to Graham:  No, not as I know.  I am currently in a hotel.  Am I hacked?  nothing else wired though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the Gnome Extension Workspace Indicator.

[image]

It will increment as you switch between workspaces using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> and decrease according to which Workspace you have in view if you use the up arrow combination from (say) Workspace 2.

If it troubles you, you can turn the indicator OFF by clicking on the slider so that OFF is exposed as in the graphic.

You can access the Installed Extensions page by going to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ on your PC.

The use of Workspaces is a whole different topic to explore if you are not sure about using them but turning OFF the indicator will not affect its use nor function.

Comment: I think is called "workspace indicator", correct if I am wrong.